# What is the quickest way to get the absolute uri for the root of the app in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the simplest way to get: `http://www.[Domain].com` in asp.net?

There doesn't seem to be one method which can do this, the only way I know is to do some string acrobatics on server variables or Request.Url. Anyone?

Comment: CMS has what I was looking for, something succint and memorable, Stephen Bayer gets a vote for the polish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port)
```

And you'll get the [generic URI syntax](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html)  <protocol>://<host>:<port>

Comment: I like that, but what if you don't want the port, if the port is 80..?? --
String.Format((Request.Url.Port != 80)?"{0}://{1}:{2}":"{0}://{1}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port) .... or will that break because there's no {2} in some cases

Comment: This won't work if your app is deployed to a virtual directory.

Answer (score 3):

We can use Uri and his baseUri constructor :

- `new Uri(this.Request.Url, "/")` for the root of the website
- `new Uri(this.Request.Url, this.Request.ResolveUrl("~/"))` for the root of the website

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ResolveUrl("~/")
```

It maps to the root of the application.  now if you are inside of a virtual directory you will need to do a bit more work.

**Edit**

Old posting contained incorrect method call!

Comment: that gives the physical path name, not exactly what he was looking for. ok, well... not at all.

Answer (score 2):

I really like the way CMS handled this question the best, using the String.Format, and the Page.Request variables.  I'd just like to tweak it slightly.  I just tested it on one of my pages, so, i'll copy the code here:

```
String baseURL = string.Format(
   (Request.Url.Port != 80) ? "{0}://{1}:{2}" : "{0}://{1}", 
    Request.Url.Scheme, 
    Request.Url.Host, 
    Request.Url.Port)
```

Comment: Don't forget HTTPS on port 443 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Web.UI.Page.Request.Url
```

Comment: This will give the full URL of the page

Comment: Try this:  Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT_SECURE"] + Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] +
Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"] + 
Request.ApplicationPath;

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Request.Url.Host
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this property on Page to handle cases virtual directories and default ports:

```
string FullApplicationPath {
    get {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}://{1}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host);

        if (!Request.Url.IsDefaultPort)
            sb.AppendFormat(":{0}", Request.Url.Port);

        if (!string.Equals("/", Request.ApplicationPath))
            sb.Append(Request.ApplicationPath);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method handles http/https, port numbers and query strings.

```
'Returns current page URL 
Function fullurl() As String
    Dim strProtocol, strHost, strPort, strurl, strQueryString As String
    strProtocol = Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")
    strPort = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")
    strHost = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
    strurl = Request.ServerVariables("url")
    strQueryString = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")

    If strProtocol = "off" Then
        strProtocol = "http://"
    Else
        strProtocol = "https://"
    End If

    If strPort <> "80" Then
        strPort = ":" & strPort
    Else
        strPort = ""
    End If

    If strQueryString.Length > 0 Then
        strQueryString = "?" & strQueryString
    End If

    Return strProtocol & strHost & strPort & strurl & strQueryString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with something similar, I needed a way to programatically set the  tag to point to my website root.

The accepted solution wasn't working for me because of localhost and virtual directories stuff.

So I came up with the following solution, it works on localhost with or without virtual directories and of course under IIS Websites.

```
string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}{3}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port, ResolveUrl("~")
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the best of what I've seen on this question so far, this one takes care of:

1. http and https
2. standard ports (80, 443) and non standard
3. application hosted in a sub-folder of the root

   ```
   string url = String.Format(
       Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "{0}://{1}{3}" : "{0}://{1}:{2}{3}",
       Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host,
       Request.Url.Port, ResolveUrl("~/"));
   ```